# I'm trying to insert data to MySQL, there is no error but data is not inserting?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to insert data to MySQL but its not working. Here is not showing any error in this code.

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if(!$connection) {
    echo 'Server Not Found';
}
else {
    echo 'Server Found';
}

// Establishing Connection with Server
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection,"colleges"); // Selecting Database from Server
if (!$db) {
    echo 'Databaje Not Found';
}
else {
    echo 'Databaje  found';
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];

    if($name !=''||$email !='') {
        //Insert Query of SQL
        $query = mysqli_query("insert into students(student_name, student_email, student_contact,student_adress) values ('$name', '$email', '$contact', '$address')", $connection);

        echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
    }
}

mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection with Server

?>
```

Comment: Which of the echo messages do you get as response?

Comment: At a guess `student_adress` should be `student_address`

Comment: $connection comes first in mysqli_query()

Comment: student_adress is database name that's why I wrote it...

Comment: Your query has an SQL injection vulnerability - use parameter binding instead.

Comment: Also, you have not checked the query for success before declaring it a success - aside from the missing param, you should test `$query`.

Comment: sorry i can not understand ur word ? @ ma3x

Comment: what is parameter binding ??@halfer

Comment: What @Ma3x is asking is does it echo `Data Inserted successfully...` or `Insertion failed`. Assuming it is the data insertion echo, I would look into @halfer 's recommendation of testing the actual query string.

Comment: yap it is data insertion echo ....And still now code is not working ??

Answer (score 0):

In your $query, write the $connection first and then write the insert query afyer adding a comma. This will help. Also use mysqli_error() function to see the errors in the query if $query still fails.